# Error when trying to use a custom exception in a static method

Tags: java, exception, static-methods

I have a java class called Exercise08.java. In this class I made the inner class `HexFormatException` which extends `NumberFormatException`.

```
public class HexFormatException extends NumberFormatException {
  public HexFormatException() {
    super();
  }
}
```

I also have the static method `hexToDecimal(String)` which is supposed to throw a `HexFormatException` error if the String is not a hexadecimal.

```
/** Converts hexadecimal to decimal.
  @param hex The hexadecimal
  @return The decimal value of hex
  @throws HexFormatException if hex is not a hexadecimal
*/
public static int hexToDecimal(String hex) throws HexFormatException {
  // Check if hex is a hexadecimal. Throw Exception if not.
  boolean patternMatch = Pattern.matches("[0-9A-F]+", hex);
  if (!patternMatch) 
    throw new HexFormatException();

  // Convert hex to a decimal
  int decimalValue = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
    char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);
    decimalValue = decimalValue * 16 + hexCharToDecimal(hexChar);
  }
  // Return the decimal
  return decimalValue;
}
```

Instead I get this error message:

[image]

I'm really confused about how to fix this. Everything works fine if I throw a `NumberFormatException`, but why doesn't it work for my custom exception?

Comment: is HexFormatException a inner class?

Comment: @reyad Yes it is. I see from the answers below that I failed to make the inner class static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use inner class in static method it must be static too.

```
public static class HexFormatException extends NumberFormatException {
  public HexFormatException() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made HexFormatException an inner class which means it belongs to an enclosing instance. In at static method there is no default enclosing instance so you get this error.

A simple fix is to declare the class with `static`:

```
public static class HexFormatException ...
```